# If $a-b,a+b,b+c,b-c,a-c,a+c$ are square number,Find minimum of the $a+b+c$

Tags: number-theory

> let $a,b,c$ be postive integer numbers,  such $a>b>c$, and 
>   $$a-b,a+b,b+c,b-c,a+c,a-c$$ be square number.
>
> Find the $$(a+b+c)_{min}$$

My idea: let
$$a-b=p^2,a+b=q^2\Longrightarrow a^2-b^2=(pq)^2$$
$$b-c=r^2,b+c=s^2\Longrightarrow b^2-c^2=(rs)^2$$
$$a-c=u^2,a+c=v^2\Longrightarrow a^2-c^2=(uv)^2$$
so I can't, can you help?

Hello,Daniel Fischer,I can't see any solution for you links.But Thanks

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=142

Comment: @math110 there is no solution there because that would defeat the point of project euler and I doubt any one here will answer you. Answers to Project Euler problems in general are kept off the internet, or at least some effort is made to do so. My suggestion is to write a program to try and solve this.

Comment: @KBusc, answers to Project Euler problems are found preety much everywhere... No one is keeping them off the internet. For example, you might look here for a solution http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-142-perfect-square-collection/

Comment: @Galc127 well that is truly unfortunate if you ask me. I feel that that defeats the purpose and the fun.

Comment: @KBusc, I absolutely agree, but there a lot of people who put effort in publishing these solutions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Project Euler problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to solve this system of equations, and solutions to find the right settings.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b=q^2\\&a-b=x^2\\&a+c=z^2\\&a-c=y^2\\&b+c=v^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

Decisions can be recorded.

$$q=4(p^2+s^2)$$

$$x=2(4p^2-s^2)$$

$$z=2(4p^2+s^2)$$

$$y=4(p^2-s^2)$$

$$v=8ps$$

$$a=10(4p^4+s^4)$$

$$b=2(3s^4+16p^2s^2-12s^4)$$

$$c=2(12p^4+16p^2s^2-3s^4)$$

Or so:

$$q=(p^2+s^2)(t^2-k^2)$$

$$x=2(p^2-s^2)tk$$

$$z=(p^2-s^2)(t^2+k^2)$$

$$y=2ps(t^2-k^2)$$

$$v=(p^2-s^2)(t^2-k^2)$$

Or so:

$$q=2(p^2+s^2)tk$$

$$x=(p^2-s^2)(t^2-k^2)$$

$$z=(p^2-s^2)(t^2+k^2)$$

$$y=4pstk$$

$$v=2(p^2-s^2)tk$$

Then the number found as:

$$a=\frac{q^2+x^2}{2}$$

$$b=\frac{q^2-x^2}{2}$$

$$c=\frac{2z^2-q^2-x^2}{2}$$

$p,s,t,k$ - integers asked us.